# Serializing `rdflib.Dataset` into the default graph?

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I am looking to parse data into the default graph of a `rdflib.Dataset` by using `ds.add(...)` or `ds.parse(...)`. When I try to serialize to `application/trig` or `application/n-quads`, I can see that the default graph triples are under a blank node.

Is there any way to force triples added with `ds.add(...)` or `ds.parse(...)` to be under the default graph?

#### Example:

```py
from rdflib import Dataset
from rdflib.term import URIRef

ds = Dataset()

# Parse into Default Graph.
ds.parse(data='<df:s> <df:p> <df:o>.')

# Parse into Named Graph '<ng:g>'.
g = ds.graph(URIRef('ng:g'))
g.parse(data='<ng:s> <ng:p> <ng:o>.')

ds_nquads = ds.serialize(format='nquads')
print(ds_nquads)
```

#### Output:

```py
<ng:s> <ng:p> <ng:o> <ng:g> .
<df:s> <df:p> <df:o> _:Nbd6d6df5e4cb4348980c2d6ff511d6ce .
```

Comment: you could at least giving the default graph a URI in the Dataset constructor I guess? Nevertheless ,the serialization to N-Quads should indeed omit the default graph - looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

`g.add()` adds triples to a `Graph`, `g`, but `d.add()` can add quads to a `Dataset`, `d`, so you can certainly use `add((subject, predicate, object, graph))`, see the [Dataset documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html?highlight=Dataset#rdflib.graph.Dataset).

Try also the Dataset example file, it's got most Dataset operations shown in it: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/examples/datasets.py

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be in how `parse()` works with a `Dataset`. Triples do not seem to go into the default graph in the Dataset as one would expect but into a graph identified by a blank node.

As for a workaround, if you use `Dataset.add()`, calling it with triples instead of quads, they will go to the default graph, as can be seen from the trig output here:

Example 1 (add, with trig output):

```
from rdflib import Dataset
from rdflib.term import URIRef

ds = Dataset()

# Add into Default Graph.
ds.add((URIRef('df:s'), URIRef('df:p'), URIRef('df:o')))

# Add into Named Graph '<ng:g>'.
g = ds.graph(URIRef('ng:g'))
g.add((URIRef('ng:s'), URIRef('ng:p'), URIRef('ng:o')))

ds_trig = ds.serialize(format='trig')
print(ds_trig)
```

Output 1:

```
@prefix ns1: <ng:> .
@prefix ns2: <urn:x-rdflib:> .
@prefix ns3: <df:> .

ns1:g {
    ns1:s ns1:p ns1:o .
}

{
    ns3:s ns3:p ns3:o .
}
```

However, the n-quads serialization might have another issue, since it does not seem to omit the default graph label from the output, instead showing the rdflib `Dataset` internal URI for the default graph. (The trig serialization above did omit it, but a trace of it was visible in the namespace bindings that it outputted.)

Example 2 (add, with n-quads output):

```
from rdflib import Dataset
from rdflib.term import URIRef

ds = Dataset()

# Add into Default Graph.
ds.add((URIRef('df:s'), URIRef('df:p'), URIRef('df:o')))

# Add into Named Graph '<ng:g>'.
g = ds.graph(URIRef('ng:g'))
g.add((URIRef('ng:s'), URIRef('ng:p'), URIRef('ng:o')))

ds_nquads = ds.serialize(format='nquads')
print(ds_nquads)
```

Output 2:

```
<df:s> <df:p> <df:o> <urn:x-rdflib:default> .
<ng:s> <ng:p> <ng:o> <ng:g> .
```

These were tested with rdflib 6.1.1.